# Listening and logging when someone pings your webserver

Tags: javascript

I'm relatively new to javascript and web development, but what I'm trying to do is log when a person navigates to my website. I've tried googling it, but I'm not sure what to ask google for this issue.

Comment: `is log when a person navigates to my website` - log where? most http servers already have logs

Comment: do you want to track and log all the events the user is doing in your website, like clicking a link, navigation to another page, choosing from select, submitting a form?

Comment: Where would the logs be in the http server? This is a tiny bit off topic as well, but would I use the RestAPI to communicate between the website JavaScript, and some sort of Java backend server?

Comment: @SpencerNold You haven't told us what web server you're using.  Even if you had, we could only point you to the probable location of the config file so you can then go figure out where the logs are.  We can't answer this question for you.

Comment: I'm running apache on my ubuntu desktop.

Comment: I’ve updated my answer to tell you where to find the Apache logs.

Answer (score 1):

Your web server is already logging each visit (unless you turned that off). With Apache on Ubuntu, you’ll find a file in `/var/log/apache2/access.log` which has a log of each request made of the server.

Each line in that file will show you the time the request was made, the IP address of the web site visitor, the file they requested, the time it took (in seconds) to serve the request and the size (in bytes) of the response.

Alternatively, add google analytics to your site and google will log each visit and give you a nice way to visualise that.